# XSLT for iTunes importer

Tags: xslt

I need to transform a given XML to another format. This is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="film5.1">
  <provider>Provider</provider>
  <language>de-DE</language>
  <video>
    <type>film</type>
    <subtype>feature</subtype>
    <vendor_id>some_id</vendor_id>
    <country>US</country>
    <original_spoken_locale>en</original_spoken_locale>
    <title>Some movie title</title>
  </video>
</package>
```

And this is the XSLT I tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:importer="http://apple.com/itunes/importer" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="importer:package">

    <xsl:variable name="var-title">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="video/title"/>
    </xsl:variable>

<Movie>
    <Title><xsl:value-of select="$var-title"/></Title>

</Movie>          

</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the `<title>` from source XML is not selected. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace applies to the descendants as well so change `<xsl:apply-templates select="video/title"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="importer:video/importer:title"/>` to use a prefix as well.